# Могут ли сосуществовать VMWare и Hyper-V?

Tags: xamarin, vmware, hyper-v

Доброго времени суток, дамы и господа, совсем недавно решил попробовать Xamarin.IOS и Xamarin.Android, само - собой для компиляции приложений для IOS я скачал образ MacOs для VMWare,отключил HYPER-V, все установил и запустил, потратив еще немного времени смог уже скомпилировать первое тестовое приложение на MacOS, решил попробовать запустить тестовое приложение на Android, но при попытке запуска эмулятора Visual Studio сообщила об ошибке о невозможности запуска эмулятора из-за отключенного Hyper-V, и мне вдруг стало любопытно, возможно ли как -то использовать VMWare вместе с включенным Hyper-V, чтобы не перезагружать компьютер и не отключать виртуальную машину ?
Всем заранее спасибо за ваши ответы!

Comment: AFAIK нет, нельзя, т. к. они конкурируют за аппаратную виртуализацию. Ну, я некогда пытался держать Hyper-V и VirtualBox.

Comment: @Кнопкатык, спасибо за ответ, Вы даже ответили на следующий вопрос который я хотел задать, про  virtualbox. Скопипастите свой комментарий в Ответы, я помечу как "Решенный".

Comment: "AFAIK" это "насколько я знаю". К сожалению, я не нашёл ни одного надёжного источника, который бы мне это подтвердил, я просто решил, что оно не стоит тех мучений по поиску и отказался от этой затеи.

Comment: @Кнопкатык я просто установлю Xamarin.Android на макось, если не найду способа компилить Приложение из студии, перенесу проект в общую папку виртуалки и машины,и уже на макоси буду запускать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Гипервизоры дерутся за аппаратную виртуализацию

Hyper-V она необходима. И будучи установленным, он будет удерживать права на неё у себя, не давая их никому. Его можно выключить, не удаляя (опцией в загрузчике `hypervisorlaunchtype` в `off` с помощью `bcdedit`) но подействует это только после перезагрузки.

VMWare Workstation отказался при установленном Hyper-V даже запускать главное окно, не говоря уже о виртуалках. Вероятно, ему аппаратная виртуализация тоже необходима.

VirtualBox без аппаратной виртуализации... функционирует. Но **очень плохо**, в основном медленно, хотя некоторые жалуются и на падения.

Так что нет, похоже, что эффективно два разных гипервизора на одной машине работать не могут.

Comment: Вот так вот: либо виртуалки VmWare, либо Docker. :(

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с версии 15.5.5 VmWare научилась совместной работе с Hyper-V.
https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/05/vmware-workstation-now-supports-hyper-v-mode.html